# Paste HTML Table at fixed line position, marked by placeholder, in Outlook Email Item

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

**Background**
I use a .msg file as a template for mailing.

I would like to append a table (created by copying a range from Excel) at a fixed position in the mail body.

Let's say the mail is like the example below (may contain images, text styles, etc.).

> Hi (User)!
>
> Find attached the table
>
> (Table)

**Problem**
I haven't been able to paste the HTML at a fixed position. I can change the text or images, but not html.

**Code**
The code to paste the table is from [Ron de Bruin Excel Automation: Mail Range/Selection in the body of the mail](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm).
Working from there I append some demo for my scenario. I regularly use `Exec_ReplaceInMail` to replace characters from the template with something else.

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:/users/mainuser/mailtemplate.msg")

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        'this works but ofc overwrittes my contents
        '.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        Call Exec_ReplaceInMail(OutMail, "(User)", "Alville")
        'error here
        Call Exec_ReplaceInMail(OutMail, "(Table)", RangetoHTML(rng))
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Sub Exec_ReplaceInMail(ObjEmailTemplate As Outlook.MailItem, TxtToFind As String, TxtToReplace As String)
Dim ObjWordDocument As Word.Document

With ObjEmailTemplate
    Set ObjWordDocument = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    With ObjWordDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = TxtToFind
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = TxtToReplace
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End With
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

**Question**
How can I paste the table at the line where (Table) is found within the template?

Comment: What about `.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "(Table)", RangetoHTML(rng))`

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about it as simple, yet brilliant it is. Tyvm Tim. It works :)